# Would SQL Server always go through the second condition in case of "WHERE @Arg IS NULL OR Name=@Arg"?

Tags: sql-server

We usually encountered the case that select result that if not input argument or a column equals the argument, the expression like below comes to our brains:

```
WHERE @Arg IS NULL OR Name = @Arg
```

Almost all programming languages will ignore the second condition if `@Arg` is set to `NULL`. However, I find it was being executed in SQL Server very slowly and looked like the second condition always be went through.

Anyone could give me help?

Comment: In SQL Server's T-SQL language, there is **no guarantee** in what order a set of boolean conditions will be evaluated. You **cannot assume** that the second condition will not be checked

Comment: http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2008/02/25/How-SQL-Server-short-circuits-WHERE-condition-evaluation.aspx

Comment: Use `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` if you are on 2008 or later or avoid this pattern. See [Dynamic Search Conditions in T-SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html) for more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a question of boolean short circuit (which is **not** guaranteed in SQL, see [On SQL Server boolean operator short-circuit](http://rusanu.com/2009/09/13/on-sql-server-boolean-operator-short-circuit/)) but a problem of *compilation*. SQL Server will have to compile a query plan for you and the plan will have to work *for any value of `@Arg`*. This requirement will eliminate many possible optimizations (eg. if you have an index on `Name` it cannot be used), resulting in unnecessarily slow queries.

This pattern is repeated again and again, typically in search forms, and the recommendation is to **create different queries**. The underlying problem is an incorrect API design that uses the same call to do different things (search by Name, search by ID etc).

The [article linked](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2008.html) by Martin goes to great length explaining pros and cons of various approaches. Erland's advice is more nuanced (use IF for simple cases, dynamic SQL for complex cases) but it boils down to the same thing: use **different** queries for each case, whether hard coded (`IF`s) or code-generated (dynamic SQL).